# How to find if the same css class has been used twice mistakenly in a CSS file?

Tags: css

I have mistakenly pasted couple of CSS selectors in the same CSS file twice, as time passes I am being able to track them manually and delete the later one. I wanted to know if there is any better way to find if a CSS selector has been used twice in my CSS file so that I could merge/delete them?

Comment: use a smart IDE like VS Code and do a global search on particular selector in the project folder.

Comment: The issue is it will take a lot of time pasting each and every class

Comment: It will be located within seconds... Try it once...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

- Copy both files into a CSS code formatting tool e.g. http://www.codebeautifier.com/
- Format it so each CSS ruleset is on one line, e.g. p { font-size: 13px }
- Put the result into a sorting program, e.g. the sort command on Linux/Mac terminal.

There are online tools that can do this too.

Now all the duplicated selectors should be next to each other. You should be able to combine them by hand pretty easily.

Also, don't forget that different ordering of CSS rules can have different results.

Also try this https://codebeautify.org/remove-duplicate-lines

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/remove-duplicate-lines doesn't work as expected

Comment: Well i had tried that and that worked so well for me ok try some of these
https://unused-css.com/ , http://csslint.net/ , https://purifycss.online/ and also can you attach your style sheet please, and try this link also https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-remove-unused-css-from-a-site/